# Referencing a Label on a Form results in a syntax error

Tags: c#, winforms

I have a Windows Form application with a button named `loginBtn` and a label called `loginMessageLbl` on my form.

Now when I write the following piece of code it gives me an error sayin "The name 'loginMessageLbl' does not exist in current context".

I am not sure how do I change the text value of the label once I click on the button:

```
namespace WindowsFormsApplication2
{
    public partial class Form1 : Form
    {
        public Form1()
        {
             InitializeComponent();
        }
        private void loginBtn_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
               loginMessageLbl.text = "Invalid Username or password";
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: You likely changed the Text and not the Name of the label. Click on the label and see what the property is for Name. Also, try: `this.` and see what shows up under `l`. Perhaps you misspelled the label. You can also double click on the label in the Forms Designer to see what it is called.

Comment: Add more info. This code is totally valid.. maybe the name of the label is not exactly that? can you post a little markup (not the whole!) that show that the control really exists there?

Comment: @gbianchi: `text` is not valid.  It should be `Text`.

Comment: @NeilKnight Ah you are right ;)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Intellisense should tell you if it exists when you typed it out - it would also help you if you've got the name slightly wrong or capitalisation is different. Also, you're trying to set a property called "text" - the property you actually want is "Text" with a capital T.

Answer (score 0):

loginMessageLbl may have been misspelled or added on another form. Remember that C# is case sensitive.

Answer (score 0):

That is the correct way of changing the text, however if the label doesn't exits, then I would say check the label properties and make sure you didn't make a spelling mistake or something like that.

Also Intellicense should have picked up the correct name as you are typing the label name.

Answer (score 0):

Probably something happen at your Form.Designer.cs where there is all the code needed to instantiate the controls you drag and drop on your form.

in your From.Designer.cs you should have something like the below:

```
 private System.Windows.Forms.Label loginMessageLbl ;
```

The form designer is an **auto-generated** file so you can try to remove the label and add it again to your form.

Answer (score 0):

```
private void loginBtn_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
           loginMessageLbl.Text = "Invalid Username or password";
    }
```

1. As mentioned before, make sure the .Text in loginMessageLbl.Text has a capital 'T'
2. Make sure the label's name is typed EXACTLY (including case). As mentioned before, if you're using Visual Studio, IntelliSense will "predict" the name and finish the label name and it's methods, properties, etc for you. (e.g. if you type '.te' it will guess '.Text'
3. Make sure the label object's visibility (maybe VS2010 says "Modifier") is set to "Friend" or "Public". Of course, this setting will need to be changed according to your needs. If this is your problem, post back.